# simple clarification on chmod permissions - write-only vs read+write

Tags: permissions, readonly, chmod

I have a simple question about chmod permissions. What is the difference between writing and read+write? Doesn’t writing assume that you are reading the file in order to write it?

To test my theory, I created two files:

- test200.txt
- test600.txt

I proceeded to set chmod 200 for test200.txt,

and chmod 600 test600.txt.

vim inserting a gibberish string, writing and quitting, and then 
reading the two files with the more command worked perfectly in both instances.

What am I missing out here?

Thanks,
Aaronson

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you did something wrong in your test, maybe you didn't set the permissions to `200` and `600`, because what you described shouldn't be possible. Maybe you gave your self rights implicitly by using `sudo -i`.

Example:

```
touch file600 file200
chmod 600 file600
chmod 200 file200
echo "content for file600" > file600
echo "content for file200" > file200
more file600
more file200
```

Output:

```
content for file600
more: cannot open file200: Permission denied
```

Apart from that the difference between `w` and `r+w` is that you can of course just write in the case of `w`, but you can delete the file. So in some strange cases it might be useful to set this.